# Do conquered locations still help the Resistance?

Tags: conquest-of-planet-earth

In Conquest of Planet Earth, the foolish Humans are resisting the implacable might of several alien overlords, who go about conquering various Locations until the Humans finally give up their doomed efforts. Several Locations give bonuses to the Human Resistance, such as the Train Station, which gives +1 Resistance to adjacent Locations.

Does this bonus still apply after the Train Station has been conquered by the ravening alien hordes? Are the Aliens dumb enough to keep the trains running on time, even if the trains are chock-full of weapons, ammunition, recruits, intrepid reporters, Meals Rejected By Ethiopians, teddy bears, and other material that the Resistance needs? Similarly, does the text of other Locations still apply after they've been conquered?

Also, do Demolished locations keep their text? (It should be obvious, but I couldn't find anything explicit in the rulebook about this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conquered Locations text is still in effect** after being conquered. **Demolished Locations text is not in effect** after being demolished.

[The rules](http://www.flyingfrog.net/conquestofplanetearth/pdf%5CCOPE_Rulebook_Web.pdf) don't make any mention of conquered locations losing their rules text. The demolish markers replace the text of the locations they are in, so naturally the locations rules are no longer in effect. This in confirmed by the lead designer and president of Flying Frog Games, [Jason C. Hill](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/8693/jason-c-hill) in this [BBG thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10284822#10284822)

> Location Text remains in effect, even after that Location is conquered. The only time a Location's text is canceled is if it has a Demolished marker on it (which has its own text that replaces the text of the Location).
>
> Location text DOES apply as soon as it is placed, so yes, Aliens do have to roll to see if they stumble into the powerlines with the Electric Power Plant as soon as the Location is revealed in their space.